# Adding lines in the middle of the file using shell script

Tags: xml, shell, xmlstarlet

I have an xml file where I need to insert a few lines at random places. I am trying to use sed/awk but running into some issues.

Here's what I am trying to do.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Manager name="Manager1" exportDate="2020-01-13-05:00" comment=" configuration from 0.0.0.0">
    <ChannelSet>
        <ChannelEntry>
            <ChannelAttributesEntry name="/Pub/Sub/commands" TTL="0" capacity="0" EID="15" clusterWide="true" jmsEngine="true" mergeEngine="false" type="RELIABLE_TYPE"/>
            <StorePropertiesEntry CacheOnReload="false" Priority="1"/>
            <ChannelPermissionSet>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" getLastEID="false" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Admin Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" getLastEID="true" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="true" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Web Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" getLastEID="true" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="true" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Messenger Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" getLastEID="false" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Retry Service Group"/>
            </ChannelPermissionSet>
        </ChannelEntry>
        <ChannelEntry>
           <StorePropertiesEntry CacheOnReload="false" Priority="1"/>
            <ChannelPermissionSet>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" getLastEID="false" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Admin Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" getLastEID="true" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="true" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="true" groupname="Highland Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" getLastEID="true" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="true" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Aus Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" getLastEID="true" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="true" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Q Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" getLastEID="false" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Retry Service Group"/>
            </ChannelPermissionSet>
        </ChannelEntry>
    <QueueSet>
        <QueueEntry>
            <ChannelAttributesEntry name="/3m/receive/events" TTL="0" capacity="0" EID="0" clusterWide="true" jmsEngine="false" mergeEngine="false" type="PERSISTENT_TYPE"/>
            <StorePropertiesEntry HonorCapacityWhenFull="false" CacheOnReload="false"/>
            <QueuePermissionSet>
                <QueueACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="false" push="true" pop="false" host="*" name="lijhlkjnlkjhlk"/>
                <QueueACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="true" push="true" pop="false" host="*" name="eeff456987987"/>
                <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="false" push="false" pop="true" groupname="3m Group"/>
            </QueuePermissionSet>
        </QueueEntry>
        <QueueEntry>
            <ChannelAttributesEntry name="/7m/receive/fault/events" TTL="0" capacity="0" EID="0" clusterWide="true" jmsEngine="false" mergeEngine="false" type="PERSISTENT_TYPE"/>
            <StorePropertiesEntry CacheOnReload="false"/>
        </QueueEntry>
       <QueueEntry>
            <ChannelAttributesEntry name="/Orchestration/bigData/fault/gen" TTL="0" capacity="0" EID="0" clusterWide="true" jmsEngine="false" mergeEngine="false" type="PERSISTENT_TYPE"/>
            <StorePropertiesEntry CacheOnReload="false"/>
            <QueuePermissionSet>
                <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="false" push="true" pop="false" groupname="Big Data Group"/>
            </QueuePermissionSet>
        </QueueEntry>
```

I am trying to insert lines

```
                <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" purge="false" peek="false" push="false" pop="false" groupname="Admin Group"/>
                <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="false" push="true" pop="false" groupname="SBGroup"/>
                <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="true" push="false" pop="false" groupname="SMS Admin"/>
```

in each of the queue entry.

So my final doc should look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Manager name="Manager1" exportDate="2020-01-13-05:00" comment=" configuration from 0.0.0.0">
    <ChannelSet>
        <ChannelEntry>
            <ChannelAttributesEntry name="/Pub/Sub/commands" TTL="0" capacity="0" EID="15" clusterWide="true" jmsEngine="true" mergeEngine="false" type="RELIABLE_TYPE"/>
            <StorePropertiesEntry CacheOnReload="false" Priority="1"/>
            <ChannelPermissionSet>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" getLastEID="false" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Admin Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" getLastEID="true" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="true" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Web Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" getLastEID="true" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="true" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Messenger Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" getLastEID="false" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Retry Service Group"/>
            </ChannelPermissionSet>
        </ChannelEntry>
        <ChannelEntry>
           <StorePropertiesEntry CacheOnReload="false" Priority="1"/>
            <ChannelPermissionSet>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" getLastEID="false" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Admin Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" getLastEID="true" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="true" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="true" groupname="Highland Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" getLastEID="true" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="true" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Aus Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" getLastEID="true" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="true" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Q Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" getLastEID="false" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Retry Service Group"/>
            </ChannelPermissionSet>
        </ChannelEntry>
    <QueueSet>
        <QueueEntry>
            <ChannelAttributesEntry name="/3m/receive/events" TTL="0" capacity="0" EID="0" clusterWide="true" jmsEngine="false" mergeEngine="false" type="PERSISTENT_TYPE"/>
            <StorePropertiesEntry HonorCapacityWhenFull="false" CacheOnReload="false"/>
            <QueuePermissionSet>
                <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" purge="false" peek="false" push="false" pop="false" groupname="Admin Group"/>
                <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="false" push="true" pop="false" groupname="SBGroup"/>
                <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="true" push="false" pop="false" groupname="SMS Admin"/>
                <QueueACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="false" push="true" pop="false" host="*" name="lijhlkjnlkjhlk"/>
                <QueueACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="true" push="true" pop="false" host="*" name="eeff456987987"/>
                <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="false" push="false" pop="true" groupname="3m Group"/>
            </QueuePermissionSet>
        </QueueEntry>
        <QueueEntry>
            <ChannelAttributesEntry name="/7m/receive/fault/events" TTL="0" capacity="0" EID="0" clusterWide="true" jmsEngine="false" mergeEngine="false" type="PERSISTENT_TYPE"/>
            <StorePropertiesEntry CacheOnReload="false"/>
            <QueuePermissionSet>
                <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" purge="false" peek="false" push="false" pop="false" groupname="Admin Group"/>
                <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="false" push="true" pop="false" groupname="SBGroup"/>
                <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="true" push="false" pop="false" groupname="SMS Admin"/>
            </QueuePermissionSet>
        </QueueEntry>
       <QueueEntry>
            <ChannelAttributesEntry name="/Orchestration/bigData/fault/gen" TTL="0" capacity="0" EID="0" clusterWide="true" jmsEngine="false" mergeEngine="false" type="PERSISTENT_TYPE"/>
            <StorePropertiesEntry CacheOnReload="false"/>
            <QueuePermissionSet>
                <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" purge="false" peek="false" push="false" pop="false" groupname="Admin Group"/>
                <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="false" push="true" pop="false" groupname="SBGroup"/>
                <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="true" push="false" pop="false" groupname="SMS Admin"/>
                <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="false" push="true" pop="false" groupname="Big Data Group"/>
            </QueuePermissionSet>
        </QueueEntry>
```

I tried using `sed -i '/<QueuePermissionSet>/a\ followed by three lines' filename` but that missing the one that does not have `<QueuePermissionSet>`.

I tried using awk but that isn't working either. Another idea i am testing is with a while loop check for the the line and insert line if match found. I am having issues inserting the lines at that particular point in the file.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend doing this with sed/regex. (See [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/317052) here.) That's probably why your question was edited to add the xmlstarlet tag.

If you're able to use xmlstarlet, what I would do is use the [xmlstarlet `tr` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/317052) to do the transform with an XSLT.

In addition to an [identity transform](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#copying), you'd need two other templates. One to match an existing `QueuePermissionSet` and one to match a `QueueEntry` that doesn't already have a `QueuePermissionSet`.

Example...

**xmlstarlet command line**

```
xmlstarlet tr so.xsl input.xml > output.xml
```

**XML Input** (input.xml)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Manager name="Manager1" exportDate="2020-01-13-05:00" comment=" configuration from 0.0.0.0">
    <ChannelSet>
        <ChannelEntry>
            <ChannelAttributesEntry name="/Pub/Sub/commands" TTL="0" capacity="0" EID="15" clusterWide="true" jmsEngine="true" mergeEngine="false" type="RELIABLE_TYPE"/>
            <StorePropertiesEntry CacheOnReload="false" Priority="1"/>
            <ChannelPermissionSet>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" getLastEID="false" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Admin Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" getLastEID="true" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="true" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Web Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" getLastEID="true" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="true" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Messenger Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" getLastEID="false" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Retry Service Group"/>
            </ChannelPermissionSet>
        </ChannelEntry>
        <ChannelEntry>
            <StorePropertiesEntry CacheOnReload="false" Priority="1"/>
            <ChannelPermissionSet>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" getLastEID="false" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Admin Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" getLastEID="true" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="true" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="true" groupname="Highland Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" getLastEID="true" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="true" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Aus Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" getLastEID="true" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="true" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Q Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" getLastEID="false" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Retry Service Group"/>
            </ChannelPermissionSet>
        </ChannelEntry>
        <QueueSet>
            <QueueEntry>
                <ChannelAttributesEntry name="/3m/receive/events" TTL="0" capacity="0" EID="0" clusterWide="true" jmsEngine="false" mergeEngine="false" type="PERSISTENT_TYPE"/>
                <StorePropertiesEntry HonorCapacityWhenFull="false" CacheOnReload="false"/>
                <QueuePermissionSet>
                    <QueueACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="false" push="true" pop="false" host="*" name="lijhlkjnlkjhlk"/>
                    <QueueACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="true" push="true" pop="false" host="*" name="eeff456987987"/>
                    <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="false" push="false" pop="true" groupname="3m Group"/>
                </QueuePermissionSet>
            </QueueEntry>
            <QueueEntry>
                <ChannelAttributesEntry name="/7m/receive/fault/events" TTL="0" capacity="0" EID="0" clusterWide="true" jmsEngine="false" mergeEngine="false" type="PERSISTENT_TYPE"/>
                <StorePropertiesEntry CacheOnReload="false"/>
            </QueueEntry>
            <QueueEntry>
                <ChannelAttributesEntry name="/Orchestration/bigData/fault/gen" TTL="0" capacity="0" EID="0" clusterWide="true" jmsEngine="false" mergeEngine="false" type="PERSISTENT_TYPE"/>
                <StorePropertiesEntry CacheOnReload="false"/>
                <QueuePermissionSet>
                    <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="false" push="true" pop="false" groupname="Big Data Group"/>
                </QueuePermissionSet>
            </QueueEntry>
        </QueueSet>
    </ChannelSet>
</Manager>
```

**XSLT 1.0** (so.xsl)

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:variable name="entries">
    <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" purge="false" peek="false" push="false" pop="false" groupname="Admin Group"/>
    <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="false" push="true" pop="false" groupname="SBGroup"/>
    <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="true" push="false" pop="false" groupname="SMS Admin"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="QueuePermissionSet">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$entries"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="QueueEntry[not(QueuePermissionSet)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <QueuePermissionSet>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$entries"/>        
      </QueuePermissionSet>
    </xsl:copy>  
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output** (output.xml)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Manager name="Manager1" exportDate="2020-01-13-05:00" comment=" configuration from 0.0.0.0">
  <ChannelSet>
    <ChannelEntry>
      <ChannelAttributesEntry name="/Pub/Sub/commands" TTL="0" capacity="0" EID="15" clusterWide="true" jmsEngine="true" mergeEngine="false" type="RELIABLE_TYPE"/>
      <StorePropertiesEntry CacheOnReload="false" Priority="1"/>
      <ChannelPermissionSet>
        <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" getLastEID="false" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Admin Group"/>
        <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" getLastEID="true" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="true" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Web Group"/>
        <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" getLastEID="true" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="true" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Messenger Group"/>
        <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" getLastEID="false" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Retry Service Group"/>
      </ChannelPermissionSet>
    </ChannelEntry>
    <ChannelEntry>
      <StorePropertiesEntry CacheOnReload="false" Priority="1"/>
      <ChannelPermissionSet>
        <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" getLastEID="false" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Admin Group"/>
        <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" getLastEID="true" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="true" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="true" groupname="Highland Group"/>
        <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" getLastEID="true" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="true" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Aus Group"/>
        <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" getLastEID="true" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="true" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Q Group"/>
        <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" getLastEID="false" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Retry Service Group"/>
      </ChannelPermissionSet>
    </ChannelEntry>
    <QueueSet>
      <QueueEntry>
        <ChannelAttributesEntry name="/3m/receive/events" TTL="0" capacity="0" EID="0" clusterWide="true" jmsEngine="false" mergeEngine="false" type="PERSISTENT_TYPE"/>
        <StorePropertiesEntry HonorCapacityWhenFull="false" CacheOnReload="false"/>
        <QueuePermissionSet>
          <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" purge="false" peek="false" push="false" pop="false" groupname="Admin Group"/>
          <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="false" push="true" pop="false" groupname="SBGroup"/>
          <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="true" push="false" pop="false" groupname="SMS Admin"/>
          <QueueACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="false" push="true" pop="false" host="*" name="lijhlkjnlkjhlk"/>
          <QueueACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="true" push="true" pop="false" host="*" name="eeff456987987"/>
          <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="false" push="false" pop="true" groupname="3m Group"/>
        </QueuePermissionSet>
      </QueueEntry>
      <QueueEntry>
        <ChannelAttributesEntry name="/7m/receive/fault/events" TTL="0" capacity="0" EID="0" clusterWide="true" jmsEngine="false" mergeEngine="false" type="PERSISTENT_TYPE"/>
        <StorePropertiesEntry CacheOnReload="false"/>
        <QueuePermissionSet>
          <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" purge="false" peek="false" push="false" pop="false" groupname="Admin Group"/>
          <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="false" push="true" pop="false" groupname="SBGroup"/>
          <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="true" push="false" pop="false" groupname="SMS Admin"/>
        </QueuePermissionSet>
      </QueueEntry>
      <QueueEntry>
        <ChannelAttributesEntry name="/Orchestration/bigData/fault/gen" TTL="0" capacity="0" EID="0" clusterWide="true" jmsEngine="false" mergeEngine="false" type="PERSISTENT_TYPE"/>
        <StorePropertiesEntry CacheOnReload="false"/>
        <QueuePermissionSet>
          <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" purge="false" peek="false" push="false" pop="false" groupname="Admin Group"/>
          <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="false" push="true" pop="false" groupname="SBGroup"/>
          <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="true" push="false" pop="false" groupname="SMS Admin"/>
          <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="false" push="true" pop="false" groupname="Big Data Group"/>
        </QueuePermissionSet>
      </QueueEntry>
    </QueueSet>
  </ChannelSet>
</Manager>
```

Comment: This is interesting. Let me try this and get back to you.

Comment: @user2689092 - Were you able to try out my answer? Did you have any problems with it?

Answer (score 1):

You really only need to `find` the file(s) in question and `exec` a `sed` command.

Run this command from the directory that the file is in:

```
find ./yourfile.xml -type f -readable -writable -exec sed -i "s/<QueuePermissionSet>/<QueuePermissionSet>\n\t\t<QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries=\"false\" modifyACLEntries=\"false\" fullControl=\"true\" purge=\"false\" peek=\"false\" push=\"false\" pop=\"false\" groupname=\"Admin Group\"\/>\n\t\t<QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries=\"false\" modifyACLEntries=\"false\" fullControl=\"false\" purge=\"false\" peek=\"false\" push=\"true\" pop=\"false\" groupname=\"SBGroup\"\/>\n\t\t<QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries=\"false\" modifyACLEntries=\"false\" fullControl=\"false\" purge=\"false\" peek=\"true\" push=\"false\" pop=\"false\" groupname=\"SMS Admin\"\/>\n/g" {} \;
```

I know it looks messy on a single line .. But ..  You need to escape the quotes `\"` , as well as escape the slash on the closing of tags `\/>`  I also took liberty of adding newlines `\n` and tabs `\t` to keep your formatting straight.

**TESTED:**

Before:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Manager name="Manager1" exportDate="2020-01-13-05:00" comment=" configuration from 0.0.0.0">
    <ChannelSet>
        <ChannelEntry>
            <ChannelAttributesEntry name="/Pub/Sub/commands" TTL="0" capacity="0" EID="15" clusterWide="true" jmsEngine="true" mergeEngine="false" type="RELIABLE_TYPE"/>
            <StorePropertiesEntry CacheOnReload="false" Priority="1"/>
            <ChannelPermissionSet>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" getLastEID="false" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Admin Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" getLastEID="true" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="true" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Web Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" getLastEID="true" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="true" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Messenger Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" getLastEID="false" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Retry Service Group"/>
            </ChannelPermissionSet>
        </ChannelEntry>
        <ChannelEntry>
           <StorePropertiesEntry CacheOnReload="false" Priority="1"/>
            <ChannelPermissionSet>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" getLastEID="false" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Admin Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" getLastEID="true" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="true" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="true" groupname="Highland Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" getLastEID="true" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="true" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Aus Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" getLastEID="true" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="true" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Q Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" getLastEID="false" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Retry Service Group"/>
            </ChannelPermissionSet>
        </ChannelEntry>
    <QueueSet>
        <QueueEntry>
            <ChannelAttributesEntry name="/3m/receive/events" TTL="0" capacity="0" EID="0" clusterWide="true" jmsEngine="false" mergeEngine="false" type="PERSISTENT_TYPE"/>
            <StorePropertiesEntry HonorCapacityWhenFull="false" CacheOnReload="false"/>
            <QueuePermissionSet>
                <QueueACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="false" push="true" pop="false" host="*" name="lijhlkjnlkjhlk"/>
                <QueueACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="true" push="true" pop="false" host="*" name="eeff456987987"/>
                <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="false" push="false" pop="true" groupname="3m Group"/>
            </QueuePermissionSet>
        </QueueEntry>
        <QueueEntry>
            <ChannelAttributesEntry name="/7m/receive/fault/events" TTL="0" capacity="0" EID="0" clusterWide="true" jmsEngine="false" mergeEngine="false" type="PERSISTENT_TYPE"/>
            <StorePropertiesEntry CacheOnReload="false"/>
        </QueueEntry>
       <QueueEntry>
            <ChannelAttributesEntry name="/Orchestration/bigData/fault/gen" TTL="0" capacity="0" EID="0" clusterWide="true" jmsEngine="false" mergeEngine="false" type="PERSISTENT_TYPE"/>
            <StorePropertiesEntry CacheOnReload="false"/>
            <QueuePermissionSet>
                <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="false" push="true" pop="false" groupname="Big Data Group"/>
            </QueuePermissionSet>
        </QueueEntry>
```

After:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Manager name="Manager1" exportDate="2020-01-13-05:00" comment=" configuration from 0.0.0.0">
    <ChannelSet>
        <ChannelEntry>
            <ChannelAttributesEntry name="/Pub/Sub/commands" TTL="0" capacity="0" EID="15" clusterWide="true" jmsEngine="true" mergeEngine="false" type="RELIABLE_TYPE"/>
            <StorePropertiesEntry CacheOnReload="false" Priority="1"/>
            <ChannelPermissionSet>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" getLastEID="false" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Admin Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" getLastEID="true" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="true" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Web Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" getLastEID="true" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="true" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Messenger Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" getLastEID="false" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Retry Service Group"/>
            </ChannelPermissionSet>
        </ChannelEntry>
        <ChannelEntry>
           <StorePropertiesEntry CacheOnReload="false" Priority="1"/>
            <ChannelPermissionSet>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" getLastEID="false" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Admin Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" getLastEID="true" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="true" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="true" groupname="Highland Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" getLastEID="true" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="true" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Aus Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" getLastEID="true" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="true" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Q Group"/>
                <ChannelGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" getLastEID="false" purgeEvents="false" subscribe="false" publish="false" useNamedSubcription="false" groupname="Retry Service Group"/>
            </ChannelPermissionSet>
        </ChannelEntry>
    <QueueSet>
        <QueueEntry>
            <ChannelAttributesEntry name="/3m/receive/events" TTL="0" capacity="0" EID="0" clusterWide="true" jmsEngine="false" mergeEngine="false" type="PERSISTENT_TYPE"/>
            <StorePropertiesEntry HonorCapacityWhenFull="false" CacheOnReload="false"/>
            <QueuePermissionSet>
                <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" purge="false" peek="false" push="false" pop="false" groupname="Admin Group"/>
                <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="false" push="true" pop="false" groupname="SBGroup"/>
                <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="true" push="false" pop="false" groupname="SMS Admin"/>

                <QueueACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="false" push="true" pop="false" host="*" name="lijhlkjnlkjhlk"/>
                <QueueACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="true" push="true" pop="false" host="*" name="eeff456987987"/>
                <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="false" push="false" pop="true" groupname="3m Group"/>
            </QueuePermissionSet>
        </QueueEntry>
        <QueueEntry>
            <ChannelAttributesEntry name="/7m/receive/fault/events" TTL="0" capacity="0" EID="0" clusterWide="true" jmsEngine="false" mergeEngine="false" type="PERSISTENT_TYPE"/>
            <StorePropertiesEntry CacheOnReload="false"/>
        </QueueEntry>
       <QueueEntry>
            <ChannelAttributesEntry name="/Orchestration/bigData/fault/gen" TTL="0" capacity="0" EID="0" clusterWide="true" jmsEngine="false" mergeEngine="false" type="PERSISTENT_TYPE"/>
            <StorePropertiesEntry CacheOnReload="false"/>
            <QueuePermissionSet>
                <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="true" purge="false" peek="false" push="false" pop="false" groupname="Admin Group"/>
                <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="false" push="true" pop="false" groupname="SBGroup"/>
                <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="true" push="false" pop="false" groupname="SMS Admin"/>

                <QueueGroupACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" purge="false" peek="false" push="true" pop="false" groupname="Big Data Group"/>
            </QueuePermissionSet>
        </QueueEntry>
```

Comment: It failed to add the lines for the 7m/receive/fault/events. I was able achieve the same result as yours using sed.